# Will current Lenovo Thinkpad E560 run with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

I am thinking of switching to Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows. I plan to run it on:

```
Lenovo ThinkPad E560 20EV000R
 - 15.6" Full-HD IPS display
 - Intel Core i5-6200U CPU
 - 8GB RAM
 - 1TB HDD
 - Intel HD Graphics 520
 - Conexant CX20751-21Z
```

Does anyone know if  Ubuntu will run perfectly straight out of the box on my laptop or if there will be loads of alterations to carry out later (which wouldn't be too nice for a newcomer). Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: You can always try using a bootable USB to check if Ubuntu runs well

Comment: You should use **16.10** so that you get the latest kernel.

Comment: I don't expect any issue. The notebook is powerful enough to run any Ubuntu flavor. It has Intel Graphics which usually just work and everything else look pretty standard. I subscribe to both advices above. The proof in on the pudding

Comment: My t560s is probably the same generation and runs fine. Only thing not working is the fingerprint sensor and I don't mind. (Also after suspend I need to switch to a console and back to get my mouse back. But that's manageable)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a hardware compatibility question.

Answer (score 1):

It will work perfectly fine out of the box. However, there is a current and unfortunately persistent C-state bug regarding current Skylake CPUs- Skylake processors are unable to achieve a sleep state farther than C3, resulting in increase power drain and reducing the life of the CPU (aka, worse battery life when sleeping/idle).

The new kernel may or may not fix your issues. Some people have found success in disabling certain devices (I fixed the C-state issue on my HP laptop by disabling the Ethernet port, others have disabled the SD Card reader, etc.). You may need to do quite a bit of poking around if you want decent battery life on this machine. If you want to check the C-states of your CPU, install `powertop` and view "Idle Stats".

Other than that, Ubuntu should work perfectly fine, albeit with possible power drain issues.